# How to check if a variable has the same value as a fetch()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently creating a website where the user can login to an account. For this I need to check if the email and password that has been submitted by the user is the same as those in the MySQL database.

This is my code for this;

```
<h2> Log in to an existing account </h2>
<form action = "account.php" method = "POST" id = "log">
    <p><label> Email </label> <input type = "text" name = "logmail" ></p>
    <p><label> Password </label> <input type = "password" name = "logpass"></p>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "Log in"></p>

if(!empty($_POST['logmail']) && !empty($_POST['logpass']))
{
    $sql = ("SELECT customer_mail FROM customer_user WHERE customer_mail = '{$_POST['logmail']}'");
    $sql2 = ("SELECT customer_pass FROM customer_user WHERE customer_pass = '{$_POST['logpass']}'");

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt2->execute();

    var_dump($stmt->fetch());
    var_dump($_POST['logmail']);
    var_dump($stmt2->fetch());
    var_dump($_POST['logpass']);

    if($stmt->fetch()[0] == $_POST['logmail'])
    {       
        if($stmt->fetch()[0] == $_POST['logpass'])
        {
            echo "Logged in";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Wrong password";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ?> <h2> Wrong email </h2> <?php
    }
}
```

When I try to run this, the var_dumps gives me an arrays stmt->fetch() and stmt2->fetch. In position 0 of those arrays are the emails and passwords of the account I'm trying to login to. They are also the same as what I type into the fields in the form. The var_dumps for the $_POST confirms this.

But even thought they are the exact same, it doesn't trigger the If statement.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Why not just have a single SQL query to return both values in one request? Database queries are an expensive cost in execution time, so don't make unnecessary queries

Comment: Close your HTML form

Comment: And you shouldn't have different error messages for wrong email/wrong password, otherwise you're giving away information to naughty hackery-type peoples

Comment: You're using prepared statements, please actually make use of them properly instead of leaving your queries vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Plus, if you're using prepared statements, use bind variables as well

Comment: Incidentally, given your SQL queries, it looks like you're just storing passwords in plain text. It's probably worth taking a look at [PHP's password API](http://php.net/password) to make your app more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Why not **[fetchColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)** ?  `fetchColumn` will by default return the first column of the next row instead of returning the entire row.

I didn't realize you were on the same table before.  For a login form, you should be doing this a bit different in my opinion.

1. You should hash the password with a unique salt for each user.  You should never store plain text passwords in your database.
2. You really only need one query:

   ```
   $sql = ("SELECT customer_pass FROM customer_user WHERE customer_mail = ?");
   ```

   Then you can compare the passwords (hopefully hashed)

Comment: This was the basis of Aviz's answer from my understanding.  The key ingredient was the combination of queries into one query.  All other caveats about password security I agree with, but that wasn't the specific focus of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use one SQL query

```
$sql = ("SELECT customer_pass FROM customer_user WHERE customer_mail = ?");
$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stm->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stm->execute($_POST['logmail']); 
if ($stm && $stm->rowCount() == 1) { 
   $result = $stm->fetch();
   if ($result['customer_pass'] === $_POST['logmail']) { 
      // Login
   } else { 
      echo 'Wrong Password';
   }
} else { 
  echo 'Email does not exist';
}
```

**Next time get in the habit of Encrypting password while Registering and Login using SHA256 and Salt.**

Comment: This is the best answer, however, please see @Mark Baker's comment about the error messages.  Don't leak information -- both error messages should be: "Unable to login, please check account name and password"

Comment: An aside, SHA isn't encryption, it's a hash. 



Would recommend using [PHP's built in password API](http://php.net/password) .

Comment: I am assuming he doesn't know Hashing

Comment: Well they won't if people keep calling it encryption ;)

Comment: @gview Well all this answer is is mine but he wrote the code for the OP.  I wouldn't necessarily classify that as the best.

Comment: I know I shouldnt be doing that ..but I am desperatly looking for job .. I linked my stackoverflow account in my CV, so employers can see it

Comment: @Devon I think I get it -- you provided the core of the answer and he cribbed from you.  Honestly what I didn't like about your answer was the focus on fetchColumn which I consider not really the point of the problem and a micro-optimization that loses the forest in the trees.  With that said, I'm upvoting yours to try and spread the credit where it's deserved.

Comment: @gview, the actual question was "How to check if a variable has the same value as a fetch()" and about fetch() giving an array.  That is why my answer was about fetchColumn.